# AtTask API Upload File

Tags: c#, rest, attask

I am attempting to upload a file to AtTask and I continue to receive an illegalargument exception.  I have read the documentation and believe I have the right code, but I cannot get it to work.  Does anyone have any working C# code to upload a file to AtTask?  Below is my code for reference:

```
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        int bufferSize = 40960; //Amount of data that to be read from file(in bytes)
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(bufferSize);//reading the bytes
        string str = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        string boundary = "----MyAppBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", "uploadedFile"));
            writer.WriteLine();
            writer.WriteLine(str);                
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                return ReadResponse(responseStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: where do you get the exception? what argument is failing?

Comment: The error I am getting back is:  00000060
{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"?exception.illegalargument?"}}
00000000

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are explicitly specifying your charset (I've always used UTF-8).  I've never done C# upload via the AtTask API, but I have (production system functional) Java samples if that would help.  Here is a brief sample that I use to specify the character set.

```
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
      .append(LINE_FEED);
writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
      .append(LINE_FEED);
```